# How many minutes are within an interval in R

Tags: r, time

I need your help.

How can I calculate in R ,how many minutes are within  an interval. For example

interval 1: `00:00:00` to `08:00:00`
interval 2: `08:00:00` to `24:00:00`

time_start: `06:30:00`
time_end:   `13:00:00`

result:

interval 1 = 90  minutes
interval 2 = 300 minutes

Thank you.

Comment: If you `as.POSIXct` the fields into a real `POSIXt` field (pasting some arbitrary date for completeness), then simple arithmetic (i.e., minus) or `difftime` will allow you to calculate the difference. There are also time-only functions in `lubridate`, such as `hms`, which will also do what you want.

Comment: ... but I'm having a difficult time seeing consistency in your sample data. For instance, the first two intervals are 480 and 960 minutes, respectively, and the `time_*` span is 390 minutes, but your desired results are nowhere close.

Answer (score 0):

You will want the `lubridate` package, they have functionality for durations, there is a function called `dseconds()` that will tell you the difference in seconds, but might have to see if your time is posix time with `as.posix()`

Comment: This would be more of an answer if you demonstrated code using the sample data and your functions here.